# Is it worth reporting a asp.net runtime error?

Tags: asp.net

I found a runtime error on united.com.

Is it worth submitting? The exception doesn't seem to show any identifiable information.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for web applications is to not reveal any unwanted information to the outside.

A custom error message should be displayed on any errors. You can let the developers know.

However, these would be just informational findings.

Comment: That unwanted information could lead an attack the useful information he/she requires to compromise your website. Ofcourse, it's very dependant on how well the website is written.

Comment: It completely depends on how well the website is written. Invest time and with adequate skills one might get more detailed information about the application's architecture and even sensitive data from the back end.